# How to prevent Write-Error CategoryReason truncation in powershell?

Tags: powershell

The CategoryView parameter of powershell ErrorRecord objects appears to truncate in the output window when longer than 40 characters.

```
$ErrorView = 'CategoryView'
$ErrorActionPreference = 'continue'
$cr_40 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer"
$cr_41 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer."

Write-Error -Message "No ellipsis" -CategoryReason $cr_40 
Write-Error -Message "Has ellipsis" -CategoryReason $cr_41
```

Outputs: (screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7RWc.png)) 
NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], Lorem ipsum dol..., consectetuer.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Other suggestions on the 'tubes, such as piping into Format-List or using ExpandProperty do not work. To be clear, I'm not talking about extracting the content of the section for use elsewhere (e.g. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/649489/avoid-truncating-error-message-in-powershell-error)). I would rather it not get truncated in the first place. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error in PowerShell is an object. You are viewing this object using a view.
In this case $ErrorView = 'CategoryView'. So why does CategoryReason display truncated when the length exceeds 40 characters? Let's have a look at your error:

```
Write-Error -Message "Has ellipsis" -CategoryReason "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer."

NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], Lorem ipsum dol..., consectetuer.
```

To examine this error object, you can retrieve it as the first element of the $error ArrayList

```
$error[0]

NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], Lorem ipsum dol..., consectetuer.
```

Not much difference, but at least we know we have the right object. Lets try to expand the properties.

```
$error[0] | fl * -force

writeErrorStream      : True
PSMessageDetails      : 
Exception             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: No ellipsis
TargetObject          : 
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], Lorem ipsum dol..., consectetuer.
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 0, 0}
```

Now you can see the CategoryReason is buried in another object, CategoryInfo.

```
$error[0].CategoryInfo

Category   : NotSpecified
Activity   : Write-Error
Reason     : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.
TargetName : 
TargetType :
```

Here you have the reason why. $ErrorView = 'CategoryView' displays the CategoryInfo object. Reason being a Property will be truncated in that display.

If you want to access the Reason, you can retrieve it

```
$error[0].CategoryInfo.Reason
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer.
```

Beyond that, I doubt there is a way to reformat the predefined ErrorView.

EDIT: There is currently an [Active Feature Request](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/816394/add-errorview-customization-functionality) for PowerShell team to add this functionality.

Comment: Thanks! In my application I was populating CategoryReason, so retrieving it from the ErrorView was not necessary. Instead, I have decided to use Write-Host coupled with exit 1.